# “System Information” profiles tab

Tags: macbook-pro, configuration-profiles

I was interested in what the “profiles” tab found in “system information” displays. Is it the same thing as “profiles” in “system preferences”?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, System Information's Profiles page is a textual report of the profiles installed on the system and/or user, comparable to Profiles.prefpane but read-only and textual. You can view the textual report on Profiles using

```
system_profiler SPConfigurationProfileDataType
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. How did you figure this out? I’ve been trying to research this through google but couldn’t find anything. Once again, thanks.

Comment: @Mike I’ve been using all three methods of examining profiles for years locally and remotely as part of managing profile deployment, unfortunately I don’t have any references other than this experience. Apple seem to promote the preference pane a lot more, which makes sense given its more user-friendly interface, and I’m glad it was also added to system_profiler since that tool feels like it’s been around forever (`-listDataTypes` is a good thing to diff each time new macOS comes out along with the rest of the output — how I spotted Profiles had been added to System Information originally).